# How to find a specific file in a given directory and check if it's a file or another directory

Tags: c, linux, directory

I am trying to change this code to find a specific file in a given directory and state whether it's a file or a directory using opendir();

I've been searching on how to do this for a while now but I can't seem to find or understand a simple way of doing this.

```
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <dirent.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *dirp;

    if(argc==1)
        dp = opendir("./");
    else
        dp = opendir(argv[1]);

    while ( (dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
        printf("%s\n", dirp->d_name);

    closedir(dp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: find _dir-path_ -name _"file"_ -print

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, sorry. I am pretty new at systems programming. Can you explain in a little more detail?

Comment: You do not need to make things that already exist.  see man [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

Comment: `find` is an external tool, and he maybe needs to make that in C code for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stat` for file name (which is concatenated directory name and a name returned by `readdir`). The `while` loop will look like here:

```
char *path = "./";
if (argc == 2) {
    path = argv[1];
}
dp = opendir(path);

while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
    char buf[PATH_MAX + 1];
    struct stat info;
    strcpy(buf, path); 
    strcat(buf, dirp->d_name);
    stat(buf, &info); /* check for error here */
    if (S_ISDIR(info.st_mode)) {
            printf("directory %s\n", dirp->d_name);
    } else if (S_ISREG(info.st_mode)) {
            printf("regular file %s\n", dirp->d_name);
    } else {
            /* see stat(2) for other possibilities */
            printf("something else %s\n", dirp->d_name);
    }
}
```

You will need to include some additional headers (`sys/stat.h`, `unistd.h` for `stat` and `string.h` for `strcpy` and `strcat` in this example).

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "use stat for filename"?

Comment: Pass the filename (relative to the current directory) to `stat` function.

Comment: Just noticed that you handle argv so fixed the code to list the required directory, not just the current one.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve what I am trying to do without using the stat header?